# Point markers for arearangespline chart in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to plot an arearangespline chart in highstocks.js. My problem is, as per my requirements I need to plot markers(dashed line) for each point(range) I have in the series(area range). Something like this,

https://www.dropbox.com/s/eokdorsk69vzjqy/unnamed.png?dl=0

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use areaspline and scatter serie with enabled lineWidth.

```
{
        type:'scatter',
        lineWidth:1,
        marker:{
            enabled:false
        },
        dashStyle:'Dash',
        data:[[1230944400000, -0.5], [1230944400000,4.1],[1231030800000,null],[1231030800000, -8.9], [1231030800000, -0.7]]
    }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/umrec2xg/

Comment: I need to to hide the point marker for the arearangespline plot(permanently) and show the marker(and the tooltip) for the scatter plot on hover. I able to do so for other chart types, for this chart I'm unable to do so. Please Help!

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, when you click on the areaspline in the legend, dashed line should also disappear or somehting different?

Comment: I just want to show the point markers dynamically on mouse hover.

Comment: No I need to show the scatter plot point markers(with tooltip) on mouse hover and the area range spline marker/tooltip should be turned off.

Comment: So enable marker per particular serie, like scatter. http://jsfiddle.net/umrec2xg/5/

Comment: I need the point markers to come only on mouse hover.
like this.
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-enabled-false/).
But if I set the point marker to false like in the above example. it goes away altogether, even when I hover over the points.

Comment: But I send you an example with markers on hover:  jsfiddle.net/umrec2xg/2

Comment: Oh, no no That is only showing the tooltip on hover, I need the scatter plot point marker to come on hover along with the tooltip.

Comment: Becuase you not hover on the point, but line. So you need to catch [mouseover/mouseout](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.scatter.events.mouseOver) event on the serie and then find points which has the same value, call setState('hover') on them.